# A bad request call to my asmx service causes a http 500 error, what can I do to make it return a http-400 error instead?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, exception, asmx

I have an ASMX service hosted in IIS 7.5. When it is called with a bad http request (having an empty string value for "host" in the http header), the service returns a http-500 (internal server error). To satisfy company security requirements, it should return a http-400 (bad request) under this situation.

I have verified that the error occurs at the service infrastructure level, and the exception is not thrown from my code. I put try/catch block around the web method but nothing is caught, and the application log has nothing. So the error occurs before my code is executed.

I know WCF can handle the problem gracefully with IErrorHandler; but that's not an option for me at the moment.

Another interesting fact is that when testing inside Visual Studio, the same request causes a 400-error, my desired result.

So my question is: what can I do to make the service hosted under IIS also return a 400 error to a bad request?